# Simple Calculator Woes(Can't get the equals button to work more than once)

Tags: c#, calculator

I am a programming noob and I can't seem to get this calculator working right. I have already coded all the buttons and allowed keyboard input(which i have not put into the code excerpt because its irrelevent) from the user but like the title suggests, the equals button will not work for more than one sum. I'm not sure what's causing the problem. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here's my code.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    string input = string.Empty;            //String storing user input
    string operand1 = string.Empty;         //String storing first operand
    string operand2 = string.Empty;         //String storing second operand
    char operation;                         //char for operarion
    double result = 0.0;                    //calculated result
    bool operationCompleted = false;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_Zero_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
        this.textBox.Text = "";
        input += "0";
        this.textBox.Text += input;

        if(operationCompleted)
        {
            btn_Clear_Click(sender, e);
            operationCompleted = false;
        }
        btn_Equals.Focus();
    }

    private void btn_One_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox.Text = "";
        input += "1";
        this.textBox.Text += input;

        if (operationCompleted)
        {
            btn_Clear_Click(sender, e);
            operationCompleted = false;
        }
        btn_Equals.Focus();
    }

    private void btn_Two_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox.Text = "";
        input += "2";
        this.textBox.Text += input;

        if (operationCompleted)
        {
            btn_Clear_Click(sender, e);
            operationCompleted = false;
        }
        btn_Equals.Focus();
    }

    private void btn_Three_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox.Text = "";
        input += "3";
        this.textBox.Text += input;

        if (operationCompleted)
        {
            btn_Clear_Click(sender, e);
            operationCompleted = false;
        }
        btn_Equals.Focus();
    }


    private void btn_Four_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox.Text = "";
        input += "4";
        this.textBox.Text += input;

        if (operationCompleted)
        {
            input = string.Empty;
            textBox.Text = string.Empty;
            operand1 = string.Empty;
            operand2 = string.Empty;
            operationCompleted = false;
        }
        btn_Equals.Focus();
    }

    private void btn_Five_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox.Text = "";
        input += "5";
        this.textBox.Text += input;

        if (operationCompleted)
        {
            btn_Clear_Click(sender, e);
            operationCompleted = false;
        }
        btn_Equals.Focus();
    }

    private void btn_Six_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox.Text = "";
        input += "6";
        this.textBox.Text += input;

        if (operationCompleted)
        {
            btn_Clear_Click(sender, e);
            operationCompleted = false;
        }
        btn_Equals.Focus();
    }

    private void btn_Seven_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox.Text = "";
        input += "7";
        this.textBox.Text += input;
        if (operationCompleted)
        {
            btn_Clear_Click(sender, e);
            operationCompleted = false;
        }
        btn_Equals.Focus();

    }

    private void btn_Eight_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox.Text = "";
        input += "8";
        this.textBox.Text += input;

        if (operationCompleted)
        {
            btn_Clear_Click(sender, e);
            operationCompleted = false;
        }
        btn_Equals.Focus();
    }

    private void btn_Nine_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox.Text = "";
        input += "9";
        this.textBox.Text += input;

        if (operationCompleted)
        {
            btn_Clear_Click(sender, e);
            operationCompleted = false;
        }
        btn_Equals.Focus();
    }

    private void btn_Dot_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox.Text = "";
        input += ".";
        this.textBox.Text += input;
        btn_Equals.Focus();
    }

    private void btn_Minus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        operand1 = input;
        operation += '-';
        input = string.Empty;
        textBox.Text = string.Empty;
        btn_Equals.Focus();
    }

    private void btn_Plus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        operand1 = input;
        operation += '+';
        input = string.Empty;
        textBox.Text = string.Empty;
        btn_Equals.Focus();
    }

    private void btn_Multiply_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        operand1 = input;
        operation += '*';
        input = string.Empty;
        textBox.Text = string.Empty;
        btn_Equals.Focus();
    }

    private void btn_Divide_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        operand1 = input;
        operation += '/';
        input = string.Empty;
        textBox.Text = string.Empty;
        btn_Equals.Focus();

    }


    // The equals works for the first sum but not for any after it

    private void btn_Equals_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        {
            operand2 = input;
            double num1, num2;
            double.TryParse(operand1, out num1);
            double.TryParse(operand2, out num2);

            if (operation == '+')
            {
                result = num1 + num2;
                textBox.Text = result.ToString();
            }

            else if (operation == '-')
            {
                result = num1 - num2;
                textBox.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            else if (operation == '*')
            {
                result = num1 * num2;
                textBox.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            else if (operation == '/')
            {
                if (num1 != 0 || num2 != 0)
                {
                    result = num1 / num2;
                    textBox.Text = result.ToString();
                }

                else
                {
                    textBox.Text = "Cannot divide by zero";
                }

            }
            operationCompleted = true;
            this.Focus();
        }
    }

    private void btn_Clear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox.Text = "";
        this.input = string.Empty;
        this.operand1 = string.Empty;
        this.operand2 = string.Empty;
        this.result = 0.0;
        operationCompleted = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think it's related to your `operation` variable.  You declare it as a `char` but you are adding to it with each press of an operator button, which will "corrupt" its state.  you should use `=` instead of `+=` or clear it between calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the operation.  You have operation += '/'.  So every time someone clicks one of the operation buttons you are appending that operation to the string.  When you click the equals button, you do not have a catch for bad operations so nothing happens.

Suggestion:

Clear the operation on finish. 
Add a default else if to account for bad operations so that you can handle the error.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it :D